# Python ARMA MLE (Implementing Algorithms from Literature)

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, kalman-filter, mle

### Overview

I am trying to implement autoregressive moving average (ARMA) parameter optimization using maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) via the Kalman Filter. I know that I can fit ARMA models using the statsmodels package in Python, but I want to write my own implementation of the ARMA likelihood and subsequent optimization as a prototype for a future C/C++ implementation. Also, when I look through the statsmodels documentation, I find that the statsmodels Kalman Filter Log Likelihood implements a slightly different expression than I have found in the literature.

### Algorithms

In order to calculate the ARMA log likelihood, I am following the 1980 paper by Pearlman:

*Pearlman, J. G. "An algorithm for the exact likelihood of a high-order autoregressive-moving average process." Biometrika 67.1 (1980): 232-233.).* [Available from JSTOR.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2335340?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

In order to calculate the initial P matrix, I am following an algorithm in

*Gardner, G., Andrew C. Harvey, and Garry DA Phillips. "Algorithm AS 154: An algorithm for exact maximum likelihood estimation of autoregressive-moving average models by means of Kalman filtering." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series C (Applied Statistics) 29.3 (1980): 311-322.* [Available from JSTOR.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2346910.pdf)

For the initial parameter values, I am currently using the internal method that statsmodels ARMA models use to compute the initial guess for ARMA parameters. In the future I plan to move to my own implementation, but I am using _fit_starts_params while I debug my MLE.

For optimizing the MLE, I am simply using the L-BFGS solver in Scipy.

### Code

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.tsa.arima_model
import scipy.optimize

class ARMA(object):
    def __init__(self, endo, nar, nma):
        np.random.seed(0)
        # endogenous variables
        self.endo = endo
        # Number of AR terms
        self.nar = nar
        # Number of MA terms
        self.nma = nma
        # "Dimension" of the ARMA fit
        self.dim = max(nar, nma+1)
        # Current ARMA parameters
        self.params = np.zeros(self.nar+self.nma, dtype='float')

    def __g(self, ma_params):
        '''
        Build MA parameter vector
        '''
        g = np.zeros(self.dim, dtype='float')
        g[0] = 1.0
        if self.nma > 0:
            g[1:self.nma+1] = ma_params
        return g

    def __F(self, ar_params):
        '''
        Build AR parameter matrix
        '''
        F = np.zeros((self.dim, self.dim), dtype='float')
        F[:self.nar, 0] =  ar_params
        for i in xrange(1, self.dim):
            F[i-1, i] = 1.0
        return F

    def __initial_P(self, R, T):
        '''
        Solve for initial P matrix

        Solves P = TPT' + RR'
        '''
        v = np.zeros(self.dim*self.dim, dtype='float')
        for i in xrange(self.dim):
            for j in xrange(self.dim):
                v[i+j*self.dim] = R[i]*R[j]
        R = np.array([R])
        S = np.identity(self.dim**2, dtype='float')-np.kron(T, T)
        V = np.outer(R, R).ravel('F')
        Pmat = np.linalg.solve(S,V).reshape(self.dim, self.dim, order='F')
        return Pmat

    def __likelihood(self, params):
        '''
        Compute log likehood for a parameter vector

        Implements the Pearlman 1980 algorithm
        '''
        # these checks are pilfered from statsmodels
        if self.nar > 0 and not np.all(np.abs(np.roots(np.r_[1, -params[:self.nar]]))<1):
            print 'AR coefficients are not stationary'
        if self.nma > 0 and not np.all(np.abs(np.roots(np.r_[1, -params[-self.nma:]]))<1):
           print 'MA coefficients are not stationary'
        ar_params = params[:self.nar]
        ma_params = params[-self.nma:]
        g = self.__g(ma_params)
        F = self.__F(ar_params)
        w = self.endo
        P = self.__initial_P(g, F)
        n = len(w)
        z = np.zeros(self.dim, dtype='float')
        R = np.zeros(n, dtype='float')
        a = np.zeros(n, dtype='float')
        K = np.dot(F, P[:, 0])
        L = K.copy()
        R[0] = P[0, 0]
        for i in xrange(1, n):
            a[i-1] = w[i-1] - z[0]
            z = np.dot(F, z) + K*(a[i-1]/R[i-1])
            Kupdate = -(L[0]/R[i-1])*np.dot(F, L)
            Rupdate = -L[0]*L[0]/R[i-1]
            P -= np.outer(L, L)/R[i-1]
            L = np.dot(F, L) - (L[0]/R[i-1])*K
            K += Kupdate
            R[i] = R[i-1] + Rupdate
            if np.abs(R[i] - 1.0) < 1e-9:
                R[i:] = 1.0
                break
        for j in xrange(i, n):
            a[j] = w[j] - z[0]
            z = np.dot(F, z) + K*(a[i-1]/R[i-1])
        likelihood = 0.0
        for i in xrange(n):
            likelihood += np.log(R[i])
        likelihood *= -0.5
        ssum = 0.0
        for i in xrange(n):
            ssum += a[i]*a[i]/R[i]
        likelihood += -0.5*n*np.log(ssum)
        return likelihood

    def fit(self):
        '''
        Fit the ARMA model by minimizing the loglikehood

        Uses scipy.optimize.minimize
        '''
        sm_arma = statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA(endog=self.endo, order=(self.nar, self.nma, 0))
        params = statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA._fit_start_params_hr(sm_arma, order=(self.nar, self.nma, 0))
        opt = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=self.__likelihood, x0=params, method='L-BFGS-B')
        print opt

# Test the code on statsmodels sunspots data
nar = 2
nma = 1

endo = sm.datasets.sunspots.load_pandas().data['SUNACTIVITY'].tolist()
arma = ARMA(endo=endo, nar=nar, nma=nma)
arma.fit()
```

### Issues

I find that the above example does not converge. In the third call of ARMA._likelihood, the code throws the following warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  likelihood += np.log(R[i])
```

which happens because ARMA._initial_P solves for a matrix where P[0][0] < 0.0. At this point, the current estimates of the AR parameters become non-stationary. All subsequent iterations then warn that the AR and MA parameters are non-stationary.

### Questions

1. Is this implementation correct? I have checked that the initial P matrix satisfies the equation it is supposed to satisfy. For the likelihood calculation, I see several behaviors that I expect from the Pearlman paper:

   - R tends to one. For a pure AR process with p AR parameters, it achieves this limit in p steps. Basically, the break statement in the _likelihood function comes into effect after p iterations of the Pearlman algorithm steps.
   - L tends to the zero vector.
   - K tends to F.g. I check this by looking at abs(K - F.g) while calculating the likelihood.
   - After the warning about the negative value in the logarithm, the above limits are no longer obeyed.

I have also tried implementing a transformation of the ARMA parameters to prevent overflow/underflow, as recommended in

*Jones, Richard H. "Maximum likelihood fitting of ARMA models to time series with missing observations." Technometrics 22.3 (1980): 389-395.* [Available from JSTOR.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1268324)

This transformation seemed to no effect on the errors I observed.

2. If the implementation is correct, then how do I handle the negative R values? The issue seems to arise when scipy.optimize returns a parameter vector that corresponds to a P matrix for which the top diagonal element is negative. Is the optimization routine supposed to be bounded to prevent negative R values? I have also tried using complex logarithms for negative values as well as changing all numpy dtype parameters to 'complex'. For example:

   ```
   def complex_log(val):
       '''
       Complex logarithm for negative values

       Returns log(val) + I*pi
       '''
       if val < 0.0:
           return complex(np.log(np.abs(val)), np.pi)
       return np.log(val)
   ```

However, scipy.optimize cannot handle complex-valued functions, so this supposed fix has not worked so far. Any recommendations for preventing or handling these behaviors?

Thanks for reading this far. Any help is much appreciated.